# Null pointer exception whilst trying to use Jersey client

Tags: java, osgi, jersey

I am trying to use the Jersey client to access a remote web service. Here is my code that makes the request:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource(request.getUrl());

Builder builder = resource.accept("application/json");
String response = builder.post(String.class, request.getPayload());
```

I have bundled this into an OSGi bundle and installed it on Adobe CQ CMS.

When trying to run the request code in the CMS I get the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyWriterMediaTypes(MessageBodyFactory.java:444)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.getMediaType(RequestWriter.java:324)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:282)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
at com.myapp.auth.request.impl.HttpRequestSender.sendRequest(HttpRequestSender.java:44)
at com.myapp.auth.ws.clients.impl.AuthenticateClientImpl.authenticate(AuthenticateClientImpl.java:47)
at com.myapp.auth.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:31)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.angry_002dnerds.components.page.base.content_jsp._jspService(content_jsp.java:155)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:420)
... 126 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.(MediaTypes.java:64)
    ... 142 more

I have looked around and seen that others have had similar errors with MediaType throwing NullPointerExceptions on different platforms..

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: I dont have a web.xml, Im building this as an OSGi Bundle

Comment: Ive found someone having the same problem here: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/MediaType-Delegate-is-null-td5548719.html
They suggest it has been fixed in jersey1.3 but I am using version 1.12 and still seeing the same issue. Somewhat concerning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

according to [Jersey deps](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1727) you need to have `jersey-json` module in your dependencies/classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I've tried including this as a dependency and it hasn't changed the issue